# gitlab interface performance is slow

Tags: performance, ubuntu, gitlab, gitlab-ee

My `gitlab` is slow when I switch between projects in the web interface. I have loading times between `1000ms` to `2000ms`. It's run in my local network and i have the following configuration. 4 CPUs 6GB memory, SSD Disks and Ubuntu 20. My gitlab version is `13.8.4-ee`. Our Gitlab runners run on an other machine. What else can I improve to optimize the performance?

I have optimized the configuration `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`

```
puma['worker_processes'] = 4
puma['min_threads'] = 6
postgresql['shared_buffers'] = "2GB"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now found a way to get detailed logs over which I can continue my analysis. Also I checked other Gitlab installations and the load times to display the whole project should be in the range of '1000ms'.

**Enable the Performance Bar via the Admin Area**

1. Sign in as a user with Administrator permissions.
2. In the menu bar, click Admin Area.
3. Navigate to Settings > Metrics and profiling (admin/application_settings/metrics_and_profiling), and expand the section Profiling - Performance bar.
4. Click Enable access to the Performance Bar.
5. In the Allowed group field, provide the full path of the group allowed to access the GitLab Performance Bar.
6. Click Save changes

After enabling the GitLab Performance Bar, press the `p` + `b` key

Comment: did you manage to speed things up? Ifso what changes did you perform and why?

Comment: i see the performance issue effect on gitlab.com too